# Issue with Angular.js and Angular Style Guide

Tags: angularjs, promise

I'm having an issue correctly getting a data service to work as I try to follow the Angular Style Guide (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#data-services)

I'm sure it's something obvious to the more experienced but I can't get the data set to assign properly to the vm.items outside of the

Data Service

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('portfolioApp')
    .factory('portfolioService', portfolioService);

    portfolioService.$inject = ['$http', 'logger'];

    function portfolioService($http, logger) {

        return {

            getPortfolioData: getPortfolioData,

        };

    function getPortfolioData() {

        return $http.get('./assets/portfolio/portfolioItems.json')
            .then(getPortfolioDataComplete)
            .catch(getPortfolioDataFail);

        function getPortfolioDataComplete(response) {
            return response.data;

        }

        function getPortfolioDataFail(error) {

            logger.error('XHR Failed for getPortfolioData.' + error.data);
        }
    }
}
}());
```

Controller

```
.controller('portfolioController', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', 'logger', 'portfolioService', function($scope, $http, $stateParams, logger,     portfolioService) {

var vm = this;
vm.items = [];

activate();

function activate() {
    return getData().then(function() {
        logger.info('Activate the portfolio view');

    });
}

function getData() {
    return portfolioService.getPortfolioData()
        .then(function(data) {
            vm.items = data;
            return vm.items;
        });
}   

console.log("test")
console.log(vm.items);
console.log("test")

}])
```

Comment: Are your functions chained?

Comment: Not exactly clear on what you're asking? My service is in its own file chained but my controllers are still residing in the main app.js file chained. I'm really walking through the guide at this point trying to modify practices.

Comment: Your `getData()` function runs asynchronously since it's a promise, that's why when you call activate, it will run the succeeding lines of codes in your case your `console .log`  and at the time your console.log hits, your promise is not yet finished executing that's why your `vm.items` is still an empty array at the moment . If you try to put your console.log inside the `.then` you can see the result because it is the time that the promise has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getData` function is a promise, so it's run asynchronously. Your `console.log` are called before the end of the promise so the `vm.items` is still empty.

Try to put the log in the `then` callback.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about it the wrong way when I was trying to trouble shoot it, makes sense now.